# Flutter: Dropdown is not working when adding Scroll on datatable

Tags: api, flutter, datatable, scrollview, dio

I am modifying datatable row data on the basis of dropdown selected value.

here is my code

```
class MyAttendance extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _MyAttendanceState createState() => _MyAttendanceState();
}

class _MyAttendanceState extends State<MyAttendance> {
  List<History> _historyList;
  String _selectedLeave;
  int monthIndex;
  int month;
  var monthsList=<String>[
      'January',
      'Febuary',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'Augest',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
  ];
  String getdate="";
    void _getDate() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    setState(() {
      getdate = formattedDateTime;
     print("date  "+getdate);
    });
  }
  _userDetails() async{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
          getname=myPrefs.getString('name');         
        }); 
   }
   void initState() {
      _userDetails();
      _getDate();
      _getRecord();
    }
  Future<List<History>> _getRecord() async{
   Dio dio=new Dio();
   var data={
     'username':getname,
     'month':month
   };
   return dio
    .post(localhostUrlAttendanceHistory,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse) async {
        var jsonData=onResponse.data['data'];
        List<History> historyList = [];
        for (var h in jsonData) {
          History history = History(
            h["Date"], 
            h["TimeIn"], 
            h["TimeOut"],
          );
          historyList.add(history);
        }
        return historyList;
      })
      .catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
       
    });
  }
  Widget attendanceHistory(List<History> historyList)=>  
  DataTable(columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(label: Text("Date"),
    DataColumn(label: Text("Time in" ),
    DataColumn(label: Text("Time out")
  ],
  rows: 
  historyList
  .map((element)=>DataRow(
    cells: <DataCell>[
    DataCell(Text(element.date)),
    DataCell(Text(element.timeIn)),
    DataCell(Text(element.timeOut)),
  ])
  ).toList());
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
    body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
           Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 80, 10, 0),
        child:
        DropdownButton<String>(   // here is my dropdown
        
        value: _selectedLeave==null?null:monthsList[monthIndex],
        
        items: 
          monthsList   
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value)
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint:Text(
            "Please choose a month",
          ),
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedLeave=value;
              monthIndex = monthsList.indexOf(value);
              month=monthIndex+1;
              print(month);
              print(_selectedLeave);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),

    SingleChildScrollView(  
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, // i am adding scroll here 
    child:Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 150, 10, 0),
    child: FutureBuilder(   //line 266 is this
    future: _getRecord(),
    
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<History>> snapshot) {
      // Check if the data has been received.
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // Return the widget and provide the received data.
        return attendanceHistory(snapshot.data);
      }
     return attendanceHistory(snapshot.data);
    }
  ),
),)

    ]));
  }
}
```

and it's giving me this error too,
[image]

i comment on code line 266

I am actually, getting the data on datatable row from the api. i am storing data on JsonData and then using loop to store that data in a list. it's working but still giving me this error. and when i add scrollbar, my dropdown is not working.

please help if someone can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So, i was adding scroll view in a wrong way, here is the solution.

```
class MyAttendance extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _MyAttendanceState createState() => _MyAttendanceState();
}

class _MyAttendanceState extends State<MyAttendance> {
  List<History> _historyList;
  String _selectedLeave;
  int monthIndex;
  int month;
  var monthsList=<String>[
      'January',
      'Febuary',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'Augest',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
  ];
  String getdate="";
    void _getDate() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    setState(() {
      getdate = formattedDateTime;
     print("date  "+getdate);
    });
  }
  _userDetails() async{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
          getname=myPrefs.getString('name');         
        }); 
   }
   void initState() {
      _userDetails();
      _getDate();
      _getRecord();
    }
  Future<List<History>> _getRecord() async{
   Dio dio=new Dio();
   var data={
     'username':getname,
     'month':month
   };
   return dio
    .post(localhostUrlAttendanceHistory,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse) async {
        var jsonData=onResponse.data['data'];
        List<History> historyList = [];
        for (var h in jsonData) {
          History history = History(
            h["Date"], 
            h["TimeIn"], 
            h["TimeOut"],
          );
          historyList.add(history);
        }
        return historyList;
      })
      .catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
       
    });
  }
  Widget attendanceHistory(List<History> historyList)=>  
  DataTable(columns: <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(label: Text("Date"),
    DataColumn(label: Text("Time in" ),
    DataColumn(label: Text("Time out")
  ],
  rows: 
  historyList
  .map((element)=>DataRow(
    cells: <DataCell>[
    DataCell(Text(element.date)),
    DataCell(Text(element.timeIn)),
    DataCell(Text(element.timeOut)),
  ])
  ).toList());
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
    body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
           Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 80, 10, 0),
        child:
        DropdownButton<String>(   // here is my dropdown
        
        value: _selectedLeave==null?null:monthsList[monthIndex],
        
        items: 
          monthsList   
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value)
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint:Text(
            "Please choose a month",
          ),
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedLeave=value;
              monthIndex = monthsList.indexOf(value);
              month=monthIndex+1;
              print(month);
              print(_selectedLeave);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),

    Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 150, 10, 0),
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    
    child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _getRecord(),
    
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<History>> snapshot) {
      // Check if the data has been received.
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // Return the widget and provide the received data.
        return attendanceHistory(snapshot.data);
      }
     return attendanceHistory(snapshot.data);
    }
  ),
),)

   

    ]));
  }
}
```